# Possible ways to get from St. Petersburg to Helsinki (or the other way around)

Tags: transit, russia, finland, helsinki

I'm looking for ways to get there without a private car and a group of 4-6 people in the middle of May. I'll name some of the possible solutions I've found, but I wasn't able to get much information on those. I hope that some of you are locals or did already travel this distance to help me to evaluate the best possible way.

**1. Plane:** 
Boring and extremely expensive for a flight < 1h (~130€).

**2. Train:**
The fastest one is pretty expensive too and I didn't find any reports (if it is worthy) nor a timetable for May '18.

The slower one is probably pretty cool as you are able to see more of the landscape but I didn't find any information for this one.

**3. Ferry:**
This one is the probably the most interesting one but I wasn't able to find any information about pricing and duration. There even wasn't a timetable for any timespan.

**4.Bus:**
Probably the worst one as it takes really long and is most likely a bad experience, even though it might be the cheapest one.

**5.Car rental:**
I didn't find any company that has an offer for those two locations (I did only a little research on German websites).

I'm not necessarily looking for the cheapest and fastest method, but also for a way to travel the distance and having a great time with my friends and to see something from the two countries. As we don't care which of the two cities we visit first, both directions can be taken into account.

Comment: You seem too have identified the likely routes. Only you can determine what's best for your group. I'm voting to close as opinion-based. If you have a specific question about a particular option then we may be able to help.

Comment: See also this Q&A for cheap train and minibus options: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18045/what-are-the-cheapest-trains-from-helsinki-to-saint-petersburg/18161#18161

Comment: The only thing I’m confused about is you mentioning two different trains. Afaik, the only choices are the night train from Moscow and the Allegro high-speed train. Information about both can be found on VR.fi. I want to guess that you shouldn’t be able to board it in St. Petersburg.

Comment: @Jan this is where I found those informations about two different trains. There is a highspeed one that takes about 3 hours and a slower one that takes 6-8 hours to get there.

Comment: Confirmed by checking vr.fi that the slow train is the night train from Moscow. The fast one is the Allegro, which has dynamic pricing starting at €29, so not really expensive. They both take the same route, so there is no ‘more of the landscape’. The slow train, being a night train, may well be more expensive (if you can even book it only to/from St. Petersburg).